# Какие варианты определения даты/времени (с предлогом "до") возможны?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, предлоги

*До которого часа, до когда, до какого числа...*

Все ли эти варианты возможны? Приведите примеры других корректных фраз?

Answer (score 1):

Предлоги  употребляются со склоняемыми частями речи, поэтому  ***до когда*** - выражение некорректное.

До какого числа?- имеется в виду дата? (До второго марта) - вполне  корректно.

Корректно спросить  и "До которого часа?", "До какого времени?, "До каких пор?", "До скОльких?" (разговорное)

Можно и без **ДО**: "Как долго?"

Словарь трудностей русского языка утверждает:

> Традиционная форма вопроса-обращения о времени - "который час?" 
>   На этот вопрос можно дать ответ: пятый час, шестой, пошел
>   уже восьмой час. Но и ответ с указанием часов и минут тоже будет
>   правильным.

Можно спросить и  «Сколько времени?», но в Толковом словаре русского языка под редакцией Д.Н. Ушакова (1935-1939) этот вопрос снабжен пометой «разговорное». Сегодня, как отмечают филологи, вопросы «сколько времени?» и «который час?» - равноправные варианты.

Распространённое «До скольки работает магазин?» - речевая ошибка.  Правильно: до скОльких работает магазин? (с ударением на первый слог). Или, в другой ситуации, до скОльких ты будешь на работе? до скОльких тебя ждать? У слова «сколько» ударение неподвижное, оно во всех формах падает на первых слог: сколько, скОльких коллег я встретил, скОльким людям я обязан, скОлькими друзьями я обзавелся; о скОльких встречах я мечтаю.

Итак, правильно: до которого часа? до какого времени? и до скольких?.

Comment: А что насчет таких вариантов, как "До которого числа" и "До какого часа?"

Comment: "До которого числа" звучит всё-таки странно, потому что "который" предполагает "который по порядку, какой именно из нескольких" (в пределах суток), а "До какого часа?" – вполне нормально, "какой" включает в себя и "какой по порядку, по счёту".

Comment: Уважаемая Людмила! Кажется, здесь мы наблюдаем диалектные разночтения. Я не могу себе представить, чтобы в Питере сказали "до скОльких". Это режет слух. А вот "до сколькИх" для ленинградского уха звучит совершенно естественно. Но, возможно, в других регионах ударение ставится иначе.

Comment: Это не только в Питере, это везде так говорят, но это неверно, даже по телевидению была передача, что верно "до скОльких", в орфоэпическом словаре тоже так. Я проверила по многим словарям.